# Anchor does not display properly

Tags: html, anchor

I am using Html a  tag within a wordpress page.I have given it to heading of paragraphs, when link is clicked it points to the page but the heading a first 1 or 2 lines are not visible or may be seems like hidden within the header.
i have used it referring this 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_locations

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried

Comment: can you provide us your relevant code

Comment: <ul class="buttonmenu1">                                            <li class="buttonmenu1"><a href="#r1">Recruitment </a></li>
<li class="buttonmenu1"><a href="#r2">Management</a></li></ul>             <p style="font-size: 30px;"><a id="r1" ></a> <strong>Recruitment</strong></p>@Aishvarya                     @drixson Osena

Comment: @Aishvarya this is the code used

Answer (score 0):

The link tag will scroll the window so that the referenced element is at the very top. Try adding a margin CSS style to the target element so that it makes a little space at the top of the window

```
#element { 
   margin-top: -300px;        /* Size of fixed header */
   padding-bottom: 300px; 
   display: block; 
}
```

also tag references are like this

```
<a href="#element" />
<p id="element" />
```

This will produce the scrolling you desire

Comment: I already tried adding that to this <p style="font-size: 30px;"><a id="r1" style="padding-top: 40px;"></a> <strong>Recruitment</strong></p> i have also tried using margin @sico

Answer (score 0):

i think WordPress themas h1 and h2 tage style display none so change display block

test and same as h2 tag

test